# Getting 'The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect' when running 'wsl --list -o'

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What do I need to do to fix this error?
I am running Windows 11 Home, Version 22H2, Build 22621.3007

```
PS C:\Users\andrew> wsl --list -o
The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect
PS C:\Users\andrew>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410736/error-in-the-certificate-verification-wsl2
You have to update your certificates in WSL.

Comment: Where did you get the certificate?  There are two types of errors.  1) Old certificates that are not signed and need a signature 2) Certificates where the authority is not valid.  A authority has to be valid so that hackers do not create there own false authority.  You have the second issue.  Martin solution is the first issue.

Comment: I didn't get a certificate, I installed WSL months ago for use with VSCode, but ended up not using it. I tried to use it today and get this error. I don't even know what a certificate is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by doing the following:

1. Install Ubuntu from the Windows Store
2. Enable WSL in "Turn Windows features on or off"
3. Update the WSL kernel (step 4): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package